# Output data from MySQL to HTML on multiple rows, works in textare but not in <div>

Tags: php, mysql, html, textarea

If i generate `HTML` data from `MySQL` using `PHP` like this:

```
/* SQL query */

while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($sql_query) {
   $text = $result->table_text;
}
```

If i `echo` the result to a `textarea` I get correct line breaks that the user has entered in a previous `<form>`. For example

Code:

```
<textarea>$text</textarea>
```

Result:

```
These
are
row breaks
```

But if I `echo` the result to a `<div>` everything comes out to one line.
Code:

```
<div>$text</div>
```

Result:

```
These are row breaks
```

If I run the query in command line, it seem's to output the row breaks. But how can I generate them in a div?

Comment: Not sure, but try using `<pre>$text</pre>`;

Comment: or [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` have no effect when directly displayed in a div tag. 
You could:

- use css to set the `white-space` property of that div to `pre` or something similar to achieve what you want.
- wrap `<pre>` tags around the `$text`.
- use first use PHP's `nl2br()` to convert the line characters to html 
   tags.

The choice is yours.